# After In App Purchase what is the best way to check if a users paid

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have completed the in-app purchase portion with transaction state.

If the transaction state returns "Purchased" what is the best way to handle it? Should I save it as a `UserDefaults` or should it be checked another way?

I am trying to look for the most efficient / professional way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of product you are selling and the infrastructure you maintain, as detailed in the in-app purchasing programming guide '*Persisting the Purchase*' section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW5).